# Using constant variable in calculation?

Tags: java, eclipse, constants

```
public class PayRoll 
{
    public static void main (String args[]) {
    final double PAY_PER_HOUR = 6.50;
    }
}
```

I know this should be easy but i need to add statements to this code that will calculate the amount of money an employee will earn if they work 8 hours a day, 5 days a week for 10 weeks.
I tried making a variable to print what they would earn each day by:
double weekDay = PAY_PER_HOUR * 8;
But it wouldnt let me use the constant in a variable. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the error showing?

Comment: "constant variable" -- gotta love it. :-)

Comment: To clarify, in what scope do you try to create/print the `weekDay` variable?

Comment: I am C++ friendly not JAVA coder but why is there void main inside class ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `PAY_PER_HOUR` outside `main`, you should locate it outside the `main` scope, otherwise it cannot be resolved:

```
public class PayRoll {
    static final double PAY_PER_HOUR = 6.50;

    public static void main (String args[]) {
         final double I_AM_KNOWN_ONLY_HERE = 1.50;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the final variable in the class scope not the `main()` scope

```
public class PayRoll {
    static final double PAY_PER_HOUR = 6.50;
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        double weekDay = PAY_PER_HOUR * 8;
        System.out.println(weekDay);
    }
}
```

Comment: why not, if it is used only locally?

Comment: If you're using it only in `main`, you can declare it in `main`. You should declare it outside if you wish to use it out the scope of `main`, which I believe is what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @Henry The OP is not clear where he tries to create `weekDay`... which could be outside `main` scope in another method or something.